# is it actually possible to use hostname other than local host?

Tags: html, localhost, host, file-uri

**Complete syntax:**  `file://host/path`

**If the host is localhost:** it can be omitted and then resulting syntax is `file:///path`.

Is it actually possible to use hostnames other than localhost ? and In what situation has people ever used hosts other than localhost ?

Comment: It's all pretty vague, I wouldn't rely on it or try to implement it ~ [_"This specification neither defines nor forbids any set of operations
   that might be performed on a file identified by a non-local file URI."_](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8089#section-3)

Comment: @Phil I am not getting what you trying to say please explain clearly.

Comment: While the protocol supports hosts other than the local one, there's no definition of how a remote host might support it

Comment: @Phil got it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

"file:// **/** path" means that you are in a local network and the last `/` means the root of your file system, so if you are always in a local network, yes you can omit the computer name(or hostname) but when you want to use a file that exists on another computer on the network, you need to define the hostname.

if you are always in a local network and inside your own computer, not others on the network, file:/// is better because you aren't rely on hostname(in case of if it get changed).

but if you maybe need to point a file in another computer on the network, then you need the hostname.

> Is it actually possible to use hostnames other than localhost ?

`localhost` is a hostname itself! so when you can use localhost it means you can use other hostnames as well.
if you open the `hosts` file(in Linux or in Windows), you can find the localhost there, that is assigned to 127.0.0.1

as a side note, if you are making a website(using a webserver), HTTP protocol maybe is a better choice for everywhere, (even relative paths is still HTTP not FILE).

Answer (score -1):

I would discourage such activities but anyway..

On Windows you can edit the hosts file ( C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc ) to point to specific IP or to the loopback IP(127.0.0.1 as far as I remember the last number can be changed to anything and localhost is alias to be 127.0.0.1). So you can make http://example.com point to the localhost (valid only for the modified PC).

If the current page is local (or treated as local) then it should be possible to add link file://exxample.com/C:/Users/gergo/Desktop/tmp.html in the page and it to open the other local file. (even if exxample.com points to another PC's IP)

If you want a normal web page (internet page) to open local file then probably starting the browser with allow local might work. Check link (have not tested it)[Accessing local data files using Html and Chrome](https://cmatskas.com/interacting-with-local-data-files-using-chrome/)

Other OS and browser should be similar.

p.s. you can make hosts file redirect example.com to any IP you want. Local PC and local network are treated almost the same.